# Random errors thrown by Bash shell: cannot open named pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, aix

I have found that keeping a detailed log of every command I run, from which path I ran it from and which user I sudo'd from, is extremely valuable as the years go by and I'm trying to remember what I did. Some time ago, after browsing various articles on this site as well as others I came up with a solution that works really well.  Here is what I have in my .bashrc:

```
SUDOUSER=`who am i | awk '{print $1}'`
SUDOIP=`who am i | awk '{print $6}'`
DT=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
export HISTFILE=~/.history
DETAILHISTORY=~/.historydetail

echo $DT $SUDOUSER:$SUDOIP[$$] \|\|\| $(finger $SUDOUSER | head -1) logged in on $(date) \|\|\| >> $DETAILHISTORY
export PROMPT_COMMAND='trap "" 1 2 15; DT=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`; history -a >(tee -a ~/.bash_history | while read line; do cwd=$(echo "$cwd" | sed "s|$HOME|~|g"); if [[ $line =~ ^#[0-9]*$ ]]       ; then continue; fi; echo "$DT $SUDOUSER:$SUDOIP[$$] {$cwd} $line" >> $DETAILHISTORY; done); if [[ $(history 1) == "cd" ]]; then cwd=$OLDPWD; else cwd=$PWD; fi; trap 1 2 15;'
```

I get output like this:

```
20180919150704 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] ||| Login name: MyUsername In real life: MyName logged in on Wed Sep 19 15:07:04 EDT 2018 |||
20180919150704 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] {~} clear
20180919150708 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] {~} cd user_scripts/
20180919150708 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] {~/user_scripts} ll
20180919150714 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] {~/user_scripts} cat file.sh
20180919151013 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] {~/user_scripts} cd
20180919151015 MyUsername:(192.168.24.207)[14090280] {~} cat .bashrc
```

Fantastic! It's saved my sanity so many times.

There is a down side however; every so often, out of the blue I'll get this message:

```
bash: cannot open named pipe /tmp//sh-np.5ARMam for reading: A system call received an interrupt.
```

and sometimes I'll get a whole bunch at once:

```
bash: cannot open named pipe /tmp//sh-np.4QRMal for reading: A system call received an interrupt.
bash: cannot open named pipe /tmp//sh-np.zqRMaj for reading: A system call received an interrupt.
bash: cannot open named pipe /tmp//sh-np.y7RMai for reading: A system call received an interrupt.
bash: cannot open named pipe /tmp//sh-np.6ARMan for reading: A system call received an interrupt.
```

I don't see any rhyme or reason for it; sometimes it happens when I adjust the size of the putty/terminal window, which I don't understand. This started happening when I added the detailed history logging (and stops when I disabled it).

Can anyone offer any guesses as to what portion of the history logging in PROMPT_COMMAND may be contributing to this issue, and even better how it might be prevented?

Comment: `who am i` is not a valid command. Did you mean `whoami`?

Comment: seems related: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-12/msg00026.html

Comment: [Possibly related issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102791/3645)

Comment: `who am i` is really a  `who` command with two parms, which are magic or ignored -- spits out the real user.

Comment: This looks like `aix` where iiirc process substitutions `<(...)` are implemented with named fifos instead of `/dev/fd/N`; unlike the case where a fifo is opened directly with `exec 7</path/to/fifo`, the code implementing that doesn't seem able to restart the blocking open(2) system call as it should.